# Standard terminology to refer to the monoids of small order

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid

There are two monoids of order $2$ up to isomorphism:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& e & a \\ \hline
e & e & a \\ \hline
a & a & e \\ \hline
\end{array} and \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& e & a \\ \hline
e & e & a \\ \hline
a & a & a \\ \hline
\end{array}

The first monoid happens to be a group, namely the cyclic group $C_2$. Is there a "nice" or "standard" name for the other monoid in literature? Or a simple way to write down the monoid, in the same way that we may write $C_2$ as $\langle a: a^2 = e \rangle$. Note $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ is isomorphic to this monoid, would this be a good candidate for such a name?

Similarly there are $7, 35, 228, \dots$ monoids of order $3, 4, 5, \dots$ (see [this](https://oeis.org/A058129) OEIS sequence). For those which are not groups, is there a nice way to refer to them?

Comment: The two table give the addition and the multiplication in the field of two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is denoted by $U_1$ in the literature on semigroups.

For the second part of your question, most finite semigroups are nilpotent (they have only one idempotent, which is a zero) and usually don't have a specific name. But there are specific names and notation for some subclasses of monoids or semigroups, like the Brandt semigroups, for instance.